# Restrict available command options in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, ivy

I'm using AUCTeX (v.11.89.6 with Emacs 25.1). I have no problems with it, just a small nuisance. Whenever I use `TeX-insert-macro` (C-c C-m) I get many options I never use. For instance, when I wish to insert the command `\enquote{...}`, I run `TeX-insert-macro` and start typing `enq`. The first option I get is `MakeHyphenQuote` and so I have to scroll down to select `enquote`.

[image]

To go around this issue, I used to edit the `csquotes.el` style file and remove `MakeHyphenQuote` from the list. However, each time AUCTeX updates itself, my file is removed and all customisation gets lost.

I also tried editing the `TeX-symbol-list` variable (which, according to `apropos-value`, seems to hold these commands), but couldn't make it to work.

So my question is whether I can remove `MakeHyphenQuote` (or any other command or environment) from the list used by AUCTeX for command insertion.

---

Update: just to clarify, I'm using `ivy-mode`.

Comment: That's not AUCTeX's standard behavior.  What is the value of the variable `completion-styles` your .tex file buffer?

Comment: Are you using ivy-mode? It should use recent used command as the first choice when you type it for the next time.

Comment: @ArashEsbato The value is: (basic partial-completion emacs22)

Comment: @xuhdev Yes, I'm using ivy-mode. And yes, it selects the most recently used in that session.

Comment: So I think your actual problem does not exist when you do the same thing again...

Comment: @xuhdev Yep. However, I would like to know in general how to remove options (value) from that list.

Comment: I think you should tag your question with `ivy`.  I don't use `ivy` so I can't offer an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to tackle this problem with the following function:

```
(defun nv/cleanauctex ()
  "Removes two elements from TeX-symbol-list"
  (interactive)
  (setq TeX-symbol-list (remove '("MakeHyphenBlockQuote" "Language" "Opening quotation mark" "Delimiter for citation" "Closing quotation mark") TeX-symbol-list))
  (setq TeX-symbol-list (remove '("MakeHyphenQuote" "Babel's language name" "Opening quotation mark" "Closing quotation mark") TeX-symbol-list))
  )
```

After `AucTeX` loads `csquotes.el` (which contains the symbols related to the `csquotes.sty` LaTeX package), I run this function which expunges two elements from the `TeX-symbol-list` variable.

Unfortunately, I have to manually run the function after I have opened a .tex file. (A hook doesn't work as `AucTeX` dynamically loads the symbols according to the preamble's packages.)

Comment: If you know which function loads the symbols, you can add your function as `:after` advice to that one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and the answer given by the OP is a good one, but it could make better use of the style files structure of AUCTeX to work without the need of any manual intervention.

The OP's answer does show how to remove the undesired elements from `TeX-symbol-list`, it just would have to come at the right moment.  The built-in style file for `csquotes` does indeed add "MakeHyphenBlockQuote" and "MakeHyphenQuote" to `TeX-add-symbols`.  But you can have a personal `csquotes.el` placed wherever `TeX-style-private` points to (by default `~/.emacs.d/auctex/style`). This file will be called in addition, and *after* the built-in style file, thus being able to override its settings.

So, you can have a `~/.emacs.d/auctex/style/csquotes.el` with:

```lisp
;;; csquotes.el --- AUCTeX style for `csquotes.sty' -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;;; Commentary:

;; This file extends support for the csquotes package.

;;; Code:

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "csquotes"
 (lambda ()
   (setq TeX-symbol-list
         (assq-delete-all
          (car (assoc "MakeHyphenQuote" (TeX-symbol-list)))
          TeX-symbol-list))
   (setq TeX-symbol-list
         (assq-delete-all
          (car (assoc "MakeHyphenBlockQuote" (TeX-symbol-list)))
          TeX-symbol-list)))
 TeX-dialect)

;;; csquotes.el ends here.
```